# What mechanism in JavaScript causes a change in DOM or CSSStyleDeclaration to trigger a redraw of the page?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dom, observer-pattern

I think we just take it for granted that whenever we change the DOM element's property or its CSSStyleDeclation object's property, the page will be redrawn:

http://jsfiddle.net/peqtL/

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "bar";
document.getElementById("foo").style.padding = "30px";
```

but to think about it, `.style` returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, and `padding` returns a property.  Now we simply set a property, and how does that trigger and cause the page to look different?

I am thinking, would this be the classic "[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)", where the page renderer register with every DOM element and `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that, whenever the property changes, notify the renderer to redraw part of the page?

Or, isn't it true that, even if we change something, the whole page can be affected: for example, the `z-index` will affect itself and all the siblings' "cover up" order, so we need to redraw the parent node and down the tree, or what if the element has `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, it can affect any element on the page at all, so the whole page needs to be redrawn.  So in other words, the renderer may not need to register with every DOM elements and its `CSSStyleDeclaration` object.  The render just need to register with the top level DOM object (either `document` or the `<html>` tag element, which is `document.documentElement` and a simple implementation is, any change to its property or its offspring's property, then notify the renderer to redraw the whole page.  Whenever we simply get the value of the property, the renderer doesn't need to be notified to redraw the page.

And this "observer pattern" is internal to the DOM and JavaScript engine -- that is, we can't really touch or know how it is done underneath?

I know the implementation is supposed to be hidden and unknown to the user of HTML and JavaScript, but it is from a programming standpoint that I hope to know what is a practical way that this can be implemented, as a part of a software system.

Comment: You don't understand how setting a padding changes the page presentation?

Comment: by what mechanism is the key here

Comment: It's called a setter. Assigning to those properties triggers a setter function. http://jsfiddle.net/gD8tp/

Comment: but by what mechanism is the page redrawn?  you mean every single setter will call the redraw function?

Comment: Sure. If an assignment to `style` changes the page presentation, a reflow will occur.

Comment: So you're saying that all properties on the DOM are setters and getters under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to implement this pattern is the use of the css class. You should avoid to modify the DOM features of each HTML elements. To modify the visual aspect of an HTML element set or add a new class. In the following you can see an simple example:

```
    //html
    First name: <input type="text" id="fmame" class="mandatory">
    Last name:  <input type="text" id="lname" class="mandatory" value="Blablabla">

    //javascript
    var inputs = $("input");
    for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].className === 'mandatory' && inputs[i].value === '')
            inputs[i].className += ' error';
    }

    //css
    .error {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  OP is asking how the browser's rendering engine knows when to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

## Observer Pattern

It appears that all the layout engines (Gecko, Trident, and WebKit) implement listeners on the DOM ([according to this doc](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_flow_of_constructing_the_tree)), which means they implement an [Observer pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=156).  Each node in fact has a listener attached.

[According to a certain Lindsey Simon](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow), updates can trigger a reflow in any direction, as far as any endpoint on the tree, but layout engines try to minimize the reflow and repaint calculations as much as possible.  I'll explain...

From [www-archive.mozilla.org](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html), Gecko invokes reflow for several reasons, each with different computational consequences, including **Initial** and **Resize** (fairly obvious).  The pertinent one here is **incremental**.

### Incremental Reflow

...occurs when a script manipulates the DOM -or- a resource has finished loading asynchronously (like an image).  Gecko calls this "incremental" because it tries to *"reuse as much existing state as possible"* ([source](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html#incrementalreflow)). When you modify a DOM node, the listener automatically adds a reflow request to an **asynchronous queue**.  To optimize evaluation of the queue, Gecko will "**coalesce**", or combine similar reflow requests in the queue that share a target.  Reflow requests that are no longer relevant are removed (say, if the target frame was removed).

### Efficient DOM Manipulation

There are ways to explicitly avoid triggering unnecessary reflows from within a script.

- Operations on [document fragments](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createdocumentfragment.asp) will not trigger reflow until they are added to a DOM node.
- Nodes that are `display:none` will not trigger a reflow until their display type is changed, even if you perform style changes on the object from a script.
- If you want to perform efficient animations, `position:absolute` will not emit reflow to its parents because it is taken out of the flow.

Take note that reading properties from the DOM can also force a queue evaluation so the information is accurate.

I hope this was useful.